# Why can't I multiply AND select * from a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (price_int * amount_int) AS depth_value, *  FROM default_market_depth WHERE current=1 AND trade_type='ask'
```

This errors when running for some reason. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `.*` before the rest of the query

```
SELECT default_market_depth.*, (price_int * amount_int) AS depth_value  FROM default_market_depth WHERE current=1 AND trade_type='ask'
```